# Round the float value using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Using json i get the value,from thati try to round the values using the following script:

```
          function onLoad(){
            var output = $('#product');
            var id = getUrlVars()["cPath"];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getprice.php?cPath='+id,
                data : {type : 'product'},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data){
          $.each(data, function(c,prd){

              var price  =Math.round(prd.products_price,2);




                           var product = '<span class="normalprice">$' + price + '</span>' ;
                           output.append(product);
                            }

                        });
                    output.listview("refresh");
                        //data loaded
                    },
                    });
        }
```

//OutPut NEEDS

```
   prd.products_price=450.2500
   price=$450.25
```

also try this format but not working:

```
            1.  var num = Math.val(prd.products_price);
                var price = num.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: var product = '<span class="normalprice">$' + prd.products_price + '</span>' ; surely you should be using the price variable on this line?

Comment: @husman:at present it showing:price=$450

Comment: What the heck is `Math.val`?

Comment: @peter: sorry there was some mistake .. just now i corrected to the var:price

Comment: @SalmanA : var num = Math.val(450.2500); value

Comment: var price = Math.round(prd.products_price*100)/100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var price = parseFloat(prd.products_price).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Your Math.val isn't a real function, and I included in my code initially. Try the edited code above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = Math.val(prd.products_price); 
var num = parseFloat(num);
var price=num.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var price = prd.products_price;
var product = price.formatMoney(0, "")

Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(places, symbol, thousand, decimal) {
        places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;
        symbol = symbol !== undefined ? symbol : "$";
        thousand = thousand || ",";
        decimal = decimal || ".";
        var number = this;
        var negative = number < 0 ? "-" : "";
        var i = parseInt(number = Math.abs(+number || 0).toFixed(places), 10) + "";
        var j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;

        return symbol
                + negative
                + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousand : "")
                + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousand)
                + (places ? decimal + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(places).slice(2) : "");
    }
```